# What is the purpose of using custom identifiers [] brackets in a `grid-template-columns` declaration?

Tags: css

I have seen names within square brackets in a site's CSS:

```css
/* simplified example */

body {
    grid-template-columns: 
        [main-menu] 
        20%
        [content] 
        40%
        [asides]
        20%
        [ads] 
        20%
    ;
}
```

[MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns#values) explains that these are custom identifiers and that one can add many of them within the square brackets.

Yet it does not talk about why one would use them and which effect this has. My first guess was that they are cosmetic and help to structure the code. But deleting these lines, or replacing them with a value like `0` or `auto` changes the layout.

Why would one use them? Which effect do they have?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area#values CSS grid is not *one* property but many properties that work together so don't try to understand them individually

Comment: Here's a great article showing a use case https://css-tricks.com/using-grid-named-areas-to-visualize-and-reference-your-layout/

Comment: The [draft spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#custom-idents) has an example that may clarify things

Comment: These links seem not to talk about using square brackets.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

The square-bracket-syntax ...

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:
    [menu]
    20%
    [content]
    60%
    [aside]
    20%
  ;
}
```

... is an alternative for using [grid-template-areas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas):

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 
    20%
    60%
    20%
  ;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "menu content aside"
  ;
}
```

Here a more complex 2-dimensional layout example, using the square-bracket syntax ...

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  width: 100vw;
  height:100vh;
  display: grid;

  grid-template-columns:
    [left] 20%
    [center] 60%
    [right] 20%
  ;
  grid-template-rows:
    [top] 20%
    [middle] 60%
    [bottom] 20%
  ;
}

.header {
   grid-area: top / left / top-end / right-end;
   background: yellow;
}

.menu {
   grid-area: middle / left / middle-end / left-end;
   background: lime;
}

.content {
   grid-area: middle / center / middle-end / center-end;
   background: skyblue;
}

.aside {
   grid-area: middle / right / middle-end / right-end;
   background: orange;
}

.footer {
   grid-area: bottom / left / bottom-end / right-end;
   background: forestgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="menu"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="aside"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

... and the same example, but using `grid-template-areas`:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  width: 100vw;
  height:100vh;
  display: grid;

  grid-template-columns:
    20%
    60%
    20%
  ;
  grid-template-rows:
    20%
    60%
    20%
  ;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header header"
    "menu content aside"
    "footer footer footer"
  ;

}

.header {
   grid-area: header;
   background: yellow;
}

.menu {
   grid-area: menu;
   background: lime;
}

.content {
   grid-area: content;
   background: skyblue;
}

.aside {
   grid-area: aside;
   background: orange;
}

.footer {
   grid-area: footer;
   background: forestgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="menu"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="aside"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

In my opinion, the `grid-template-areas` variant is simpler to use. The square bracket syntax probably has its use case, though I currently can not think of one.

Answer (score 1):

A self-explanatory example

```css
body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 
        [main-menu] 
        20%
        [content] 
        40%
        [asides]
        20%
        [ads] 
        20%
    ;
}

.ads {
    grid-area: ads; /* I will get placed at the line called "ads" in the template */
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="ads"></div>
```

> `[linename]`
>
> A `<custom-ident>` specifying a **name for the line** in that location. <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns#values)</sup>

> `<custom-ident>`
>
> If there is **a named line** with the name '`<custom-ident>-start`/`<custom-ident>-end`', it contributes the first such line to the **grid item's placement.** <sup>[ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area#values)</sup>